# How do you handle ad hoc configuration?

Tags: configuration, configuration-management

We use Puppet (or Chef) to script out commissioning of the new servers for different roles as well as configuration of the software that is deployed on those. However, how do you handle ad hoc configuration changes like changing a log level or Db or queue name changes on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

Are these changes not manageable by Puppet?If you already using it, why complicate things by using something else?I can see though that it could be problematic if Puppet has not been built up with scalability in mind.

Comment: To check if I understand your answer correctly: Do you mean writing Puppet scripts for ad-hoc changes as well?

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I meant.